# Numpy get values at indices given in array form

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I want to get the values at `indices` of `my_array`.

```
indices = np.array([[[0],
        [1],
        [0]]])

my_array = np.array([[[1.1587323 , 1.75406635],
        [1.05464125, 1.29215026],
        [0.9784655 , 1.16957462]]])
```

I should get the following output:

```
output: array([[[1.1587323], [1.29215026], [0.9784655]]])
```

Is it possible without for loops or list comprehensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
np.take_along_axis(my_array, indices, axis=-1)
array([[[1.1587323 ],
        [1.29215026],
        [0.9784655 ]]])
```